# Trying to compare three values in excel

Tags: excel

I have a table, and I'm trying to a certain value if one value is in between two other values. I want to pull the percentages that come from the numbers that have the top numbers in between them. Look at the image to get a better picture if needed.
`=IF(C7<=D6<=C8,D8,IF(C8<=D6<=C9,D9,IF(C9<=D6<=C10,D10,IF(C10<=D6<=C11,D11,IF(C11<=D6<=C12,D12,IF(C12<=D6<=C13,D13,0))))))`

[This picture shows the table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKdRI.png)

Comment: It just is putting out 0.00% even though d6 is between C7 and C8 in value

Comment: @pnuts so would it be like '=if(c7<=d6 AND d6<=c8,d8,IF(.....'

Thank you very  much

Comment: @JohnnyGustafson I believe you could use `VLOOKUP` a lot easier than nested `IF`'s